# create mysql database connect to server error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

when I type: `mysqladmin -u root -p create music_library_development`
then enter my install password then enter, it gives me this error:

```
connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your password to connect to the database with the `root` login is wrong. If your `root` account doesn't have a password, remove the `-p` option. If it has one, type the correct password when prompted.

Comment: thanks, I delete the -p, but still got the same message, how can I find out the root acc password pls?

Comment: You can't. You can reset it if you have root access to the machine like this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I reset the root acc password follow the instruction:http://www.trickyways.com/2010/01/how-to-recover-root-password-on-mac-os-x/ but still got the same problem, I think its not the password about the root account. its about the mysql password. how can I reset that as well please?

Comment: The error you pasted says explicitely that something is wrong with the *root* account, not mysql.

Comment: not sure, but it still not working after reset the root password. any thing else i can try? thanks any way